# Swift: How to fetch Relationship Core Data by Month

Tags: swift, date, core-data, relationship, nsfetchrequest

I'm new to Swift and need your help.

I have two View Controllers with a tableview and two Entities called Groups and Singlegroups with an one to many relationship.The Entity Singlegroups has an attribute from type Date.

In View Controller 1 (MasterViewController) I show all Groups in my TableView and in the second View Controller (DetailViewController) I show all Singlegroups related to the Group of the selected row.

Now I want to load the SingleGroups on second View Controller only from current month but I can't get it to work, because I have no FetchRequest in the second View Controller. I transfer the Single Groups for the selected row in the prepareForSegue method.

I tried to call a fetchRequest manually in thousands different ways but nothing happend.
Hope you understand my problem and can help me.

MasterViewController ViewWillAppear:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class MasterViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var groups: [Groups] = []

    @IBOutlet weak var groupsTableView: UITableView!
     
    var groupsTextField: UITextField?
    
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        groupsTableView.delegate = self
        groupsTableView.dataSource = self          
    }
               
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        
    }
        
        
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        // Core date initialization
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
        }
        
        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Groups> = Groups.fetchRequest()
        
        do {
            groups = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
            
            groupsTableView.reloadData()
            
        } catch {
            // TODO: error handling
            print("Could not fetch groups")
        }
}
```

PrepareForSegue in MasterViewController:

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        
        if segue.identifier == "showDetailViewController" {

        guard let destination = segue.destination as? DetailViewController,
            let selectedRow = self.groupsTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row else {
                return
            }
            
            destination.group = groups[selectedRow]
            destination.title = groups[selectedRow].groupTitle
  
        }
```

DetailViewController ViewWillAppear:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData


class DetailViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    var singleGroupDate: UILabel!
    var singleGroupName: UILabel!
    var singleGroupAmount: UILabel!
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var dateLabelTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var singleGroupSum: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var singleGroupTableView: UITableView!
    
    var groups: [Groups] = []
    var group: Groups?
   
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        singleGroupTableView.delegate = self
        singleGroupTableView.dataSource = self
        
        }
    
        override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    
        // Core date initialization
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            // create alert
            let alert = UIAlertController(
                title: "Could not get app delegate",
                message: "Could not get app delegate, unexpected error occured. Try again later.",
                preferredStyle: .alert)
        
            // add OK action
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
        
            // show alert
                self.present(alert, animated: true)
        
            return
        }
        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        
        singleGroupTableView.reloadData()
```

DetailViewController TableView:

```
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return group?.singleGroups?.count ?? 0
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = singleGroupTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SingleGroupsTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! SingleGroupsTableViewCell
        
        let currencyFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        currencyFormatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
        currencyFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
        currencyFormatter.locale = Locale.current
        currencyFormatter.positivePrefix = currencyFormatter.plusSign
        currencyFormatter.negativePrefix = currencyFormatter.minusSign

        if let singleGroup = group?.singleGroups?[indexPath.row] {
            cell.singleGroupNameLabel?.text = singleGroup.singleGroupName
            cell.singleGroupAmountLabel?.text = currencyFormatter.string(from: singleGroup.singleGroupAmount as NSNumber)
            cell.singleGroupAmountLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
            cell.singleGroupDateLabel?.text = DateHelper.convertDate(date: singleGroup.singleGroupTimeStamp)
        }
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            deleteSingleGroup(at: indexPath)
        }
    }
```

UPDATE:
I solved it myself by writing a new fetch request for the SingleGroups Entity and changing the numbersOfRowsInSection method of my tableview.

```
    func orderFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> {

        let startDateFetch = Date().startOfMonth()
        let endDateFetch = Date().endOfMonth()

        self.startDate = startDateFetch!
        self.endDate = endDateFetch!

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "SingleGroups")
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "singleGroupTimeStamp", ascending: false)
        let predicate1 = NSPredicate(format: "group == %@", group!)
        let predicate2 = NSPredicate(format: "singleGroupTimeStamp >= %@ AND singleGroupTimeStamp <= %@", startDate as CVarArg, endDate as CVarArg)

        let compound = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [predicate1, predicate2])
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        fetchRequest.predicate = compound

        return fetchRequest
    }

    func fetchData() {

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let fetchRequest = orderFetchRequest()
        fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedContext, sectionNameKeyPath:nil, cacheName: nil)

                do {
                    try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()

                    singleGroupTableView.reloadData()
                }
                catch let error as NSError {
                    print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                }
    }
```

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects?.count ?? 0
```